# Find least common ancestors given two values in binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, ancestor

I got this question in a programming interview. Feel free to think about how you might answer it.

You're given the root node of a binary tree (not a binary search tree) where each node contains an integer value, and no value appears twice. You're also given two values `val1` and `val2` (which may or may not be in the tree.) If both are in the tree, return the node that is the least common ancestor of the two nodes containing these two values. If not, return null.

Assume that each node has access to the left and right children. You may append the node structure, but you may **not** append the parent to each node. Your algorithm should run in less than O(N^2), where N is the number of nodes in the tree.

NOTE: Although it's similar to the famous least-common-ancestor problem, the limitations in this one makes it not quite the same.

Comment: Interesting. What was your attempt?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I was able to answer this one, but I'd like other people to have a chance to think about it. Is that fair?

Comment: Not really, no - it's not what Stack Overflow is about. I've no doubt someone will answer, but SO isn't a site for brain teasers. It's a site for posing questions about problems you've experienced (and hopefully made an attempt to solve, which you can share with us).

Comment: Or, you could probably answer your own question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Hmm.. then that's really not my point in posting this problem. I'd just like to share an interesting problem that may be useful to other people, and give them a chance to think through it. If this is defeating the purpose of SO, I'll let people take care with the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you would consider O(N<sup>2</sup>), unless I'm misunderstanding the problem. The following solution is a preorder traverse and therefore visits each node at most once:

```
struct node* visit(struct node* visited, int p, int q, struct node* sentinel) {
  if (!visited) return visited;
  if (visited->data == p || visited->data == q) {
    struct node* t;
    if ((t = visit(visited->left, p, q, visited))) return t;
    if ((t = visit(visited->right, p, q, visited))) return t;
    return sentinel;
  } else {
    struct node* left = visit(visited->left, p, q, visited);
    struct node* right = visit(visited->right, p, q, visited);
    if (left == visited) return right ? right : sentinel;
    if (right == visited) return left ? left : sentinel;
    return left ? left : right;
  }
}

struct node* lca(struct node* root, int val1, int val2) {
  return visit(root, val1, val2, 0);
}
```

I suppose some explanation is in order, but maybe since it was just a brain teaser, it's best to leave that code there and see what people make of it. (And I haven't tested it thoroughly either, to make it look more like an interview.)

This is not a question I've ever used in an interview, and I'm not sure what I would have made had someone come up with the above code as an answer. But then I've never been sure that I would have hired myself.

Comment: Because of the uniqueness constraints, the first two recursive calls to visit can only ever return null (no matches) or visited (one match), so the entire block can be simplified to `return visit(visited->left, p, q, visited) || visit(visited->right, p, q, visited) ? visited : sentinel;`

Comment: Also in the `if (right == visited)` case, `left` can only be null at this point, so you can just `return sentinel;` (although I admit the symmetry looks nice).

Comment: @Neil, you're right of course, although I'm not 100% convinced that your line is a simplification; I suspect it will end up being at least one extra machine instruction. (Depending on what your definition of simplification is.) FWIW, the expression I originally had in mind, but edited out, used the GNU ?: extension: `return visit(visited->left, p, q, visited) ?: visit(visited->right, p, q, visited) ?: sentinel;` which probably is not a poster-child for that particular extension.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just confused as to why you went to all the trouble to save the value.